# Connect to openshift 3 mongodb from remote?

Tags: mongodb, openshift, openshift-3

How do I connect to my Openshift 3 MongoDB with https://mongobooster.com/ from my local mac? The credentials from the pod do not work.

**Pod:** nodejs-mongo-persistent-1-rt6ch

```
Connected to MongoDB at: mongodb://userLorem:ABC123SomePassword@172.123.123.123:27017/sampledb
```

Answer (score 12):

Just fleshing out Graham's answer in case it may be of assistance (although I am not so much of an authority).

This worked for me in [Robo 3T](https://robomongo.org/) (formally RoboMongo) - a GUI for MongoDB administration.

The result was that I could use a GUI to remotely interact with a MongoDB instance on OpenShift.

**Sanity / Data Checks and Environment Familiarisation**

Assuming you have MongoDB running on OpenShift, to get relevant data go to:

`Your Project` > `Resources` > `Secrets` > `mongodb` > `[ click reveal secret ]`

Copy these values to a safe place if you haven't already:

> database-admin-password:  *****
>
> database-name:  sampledb
>
> database-password:  *****
>
> database-user:  *****

Assuming you have [OpenShift CLI](https://docs.openshift.com/online/cli_reference/get_started_cli.html) tools installed, you can then do the following to familiarize yourself with your project environment:

```
oc get pods
```

will return something like:

```
NAME                     READY     STATUS       RESTARTS   AGE
mongodb-1-XXXX5          1/1       Running      0          12h
my-node-app-10-build     0/1       Completed    0          10h
my-node-app-2-build      0/1       Init:Error   0          11h
my-node-app-8-cg2v2      1/1       Running      0          10h
my-node-app-9-build      0/1       Completed    0          10h
```

You can then `rsh` into your mongo pod with the following (replacing with your actual mongodb pod name):

```
oc rsh mongodb-1-XXXX5
```

Then run the mongo shell with the following (using the values you got from the console earlier):

```
// don't do this...
// normal user name, normal user password (won't allow you to run 'show dbs')
// mongo -u "database-user" -p "database-password" sampledb

// do this...
// admin user, admin user password (this lets you run 'show dbs' etc)
mongo -u "admin" -p "database-admin-password" admin
```

**Setting Up Port Forwarding**

The above steps made me feel more familiar with what I was working with, then I could look into port forwarding:

https://learn.openshift.com/introduction/port-forwarding

The relevant part regarding remote access to MongoDB on OpenShift is in step four:

> To setup port forwarding between a local machine and the database
>   running on OpenShift you use the oc port-forward command. You need to
>   pass the name of the pod and details of the port the database service
>   is using, as well as the local port to use.
>
> The format for the command is:
>
> `oc port-forward <pod-name> <local-port>:<remote-port>`

In my case, I did this:

```
oc port-forward mongodb-1-XXXX5 34000:27017
```

So this means:

> The client listens on port 34000 locally and forwards to 27017 in the
>   pod.

See:  https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/port_forwarding.html

**Remote GUI Settings**

The settings I then defined in `Robo 3T` were:

> Type:  Direct Connection
>
> Name:  OpenShift MongoDB Instance
>
> Address:  localhost : 34000
>
> And on Authentication tab...
>
> Perform authentication:  checked
>
> Database: admin
>
> Username: admin
>
> Password: [ your database-admin-password ]
>
> Auth Mechanism:
>
> SCRAM-SHA-1

Answer (score 1):

You need to use port forwarding. See the port forwarding tutorial at:

- https://learn.openshift.com

The example is for PostgreSQL, but same principle.